# Cannot access Linux Oracle Database with Perl Script after connecting with PuTTY

Tags: linux, putty, database, perl

I have the following problem: I currently connect to one of our Linux servers using PuTTY on my Windows 10 machine. If I use a ‘standard’ PuTTY connection I have no problem: I can log in and run my Perl script to access an Oracle database on the Linux server. However, recently I have set up a new PuTTY connection (I copied the original working copy used above). The only difference from the original is that I have entered the following in the section ‘Connection->SSH->Remote command’ of the PuTTY configuration window:

```
cd ../home/code/project1/scripts/perl ; /bin/bash
```

(I have done this so I arrive directly in the folder containing all my scripts.)

I can still log into the server with no problems and it takes me straight to the folder that contains my Perl scripts. However, when I run the script to access the Oracle database I get the following error:

```
DBI connect('server1/dbname','username',...) failed: ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env var  or PATH (Windows) and or NLS settings, permissions, etc. at PerlDBFile1.pl line 10.
impossible de se connecter à server1 / dbname at PerlDBFile1.pl line 10, <DATA> line 1.
```

In addition, if I run the 'env' command on the server the variable $ORACLE_HOME is not listed (If I run the same 'env' command on the server with the standard PuTTY connection the $ORACLE_HOME variable is present.)

Just to note: Running any other Perl script on the server (that does NOT access the Oracle database) through either of the PuTTY sessions I have created works with no problems.

Comment: Have you tried `cd ../home/code/project1/scripts/perl ; /bin/bash -i` ? You might just miss your and the system's `.profile`

Comment: Many thanks Eugen for the quick response, unfortunately your suggestion results in the same error message.

Comment: please do a `grep 'ORACLE_HOME' ~/* /etc/bach* /etc/profile*` (ignoring the "is a directory" errors) and post the result.

Comment: If I run the suggested command on both of the PuTTY connections I get exactly the same output. The only entry that does not finish with "is a directory" is: grep: /etc/bach*: No file or directory of this type

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo: `/etc/bash*`

Comment: Ar yes, I should have spotted your deliberate mistake but did'nt!...Anyway after running the amended command on both PuTTY connections all results come back the same and all end with 'is a directory'.

Comment: One more: `grep 'ORACLE_HOME' /etc/profile.d/*`

Comment: This time, on both connections, nothing is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have the solution!...Thanks to everyone who replied.

Basically, I originally had the command:

```
cd ../home/code/project1/scripts/perl ; /bin/bash (See original post)
```

To get it to work I replaced the above with

```
cd ../home/code/project1/scripts/perl; source ~/.bash_profile; /bin/bash
```

I also tried:

```
cd ../home/code/project1/scripts/perl; /bin/bash; source ~/.bash_profile
```

But that did NOT work.